# Alfresco Java code to move documents to specific

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I want to move documents attached with workflow to some specific. I have done this in java script.

```
        var destNode = search.findNode("workspace://SpacesStore/55bbdd0e-c185-4ab4-a7e8-5e8d9701a5ed");                     
                for (var i = 0; i < bpm_package.children.length; i++)
                {
                    bpm_package.children[i].move(destNode);
                }
```

But I want java version of doing same ? Please help me!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To some specific... what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use fileFolderService to move any document.There is method in fileFolderService called move.You can fine more on this on below link.

http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/model/FileFolderService.html

[image]

For using filefolderService you need to inject that service.Ig you are using javabackend webscript you can do it like below in any context file.

```
<bean id="webscript.{Path}.get" class="com.yaskawa.api.WebScript"
        parent="webscript">
        <property name="fileFolderService" ref="fileFolderService" />
    </bean>
```

Below is example

```
FileFolderService().move(node,destNode, "NameOnDestination")
```

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Thanks Krutik Jayswal, for your response. I have done this by another way.. I have used nodeservice.moveNode(Source ,Destination, null, null);

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Java equivalent:

```
ActivitiScriptNode bpmPackageScriptNode = (ActivitiScriptNode) delegateTask.getVariable("bpm_package");
if(bpmPackageScriptNode != null) {
    NodeRef bpmPackage = bpmPackageScriptNode.getNodeRef();
    List<ChildAssociationRef> children = nodeService.getChildAssocs(
            bpmPackage, WorkflowModel.ASSOC_PACKAGE_CONTAINS, RegexQNamePattern.MATCH_ALL);
    for (ChildAssociationRef child : children) {
        NodeRef childRef = child.getChildRef();
        fileService.move(childRef, destinationXpath, null);
    }   
}
```

It is better to use **`move(...)`** from `FileFolderService` instead of `NodeSerivce` because of some additional checks.